# How to compute absolute value of signed random integer

Tags: java, findbugs

I'm trying to generate the random number which is stored and I need to return the string value.

Here is My method:

```
public String generateRand() {
    java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String rnd = "" + Math.abs(rand.nextInt()) + "" +
       Math.abs(System.currentTimeMillis());
    return rnd;
}
```

The Findbugs plugin of Jenkins is warning me that there is `Bad attempt to compute absolute value of signed random integer`.

This code generates a random signed integer and then computes the absolute value of that random integer. If the number returned by the random number generator is `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, then the result will be negative as well, since `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE) == Integer.MIN_VALUE`. 
Same problem arised for long values as well.

What is the best way to to compute absolute value of signed random integer?

Comment: I don't think jenkins warns about any of these things, you're probably talking about some jenkins plugin?

Comment: It's findbugs with jenkins

Comment: next question - are you asking why the behavior is like it is or how to compute absolute value of singed random integer? your subject seems to contradict your body text

Comment: I'm asking what is the best way to to compute absolute value of signed random integer in my code.

Comment: in this case String rnd = "" + Math.abs(rand.nextInt()) + "" +
       Math.abs(System.currentTimeMillis());

Comment: I've edited your question to match what you replied in the comments.

Comment: On a side note, `java.util.Random` is designed to generate a _sequence_ of numbers. You are better off creating it once and reusing it on subsequent calls. Note that it is _not_ thread-safe, but you can store them in a `ThreadLocal` if you're calling this from multiple threads.

Comment: I've never know this before, Thank you !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use

    `rand.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);`

instead of

    `Math.abs(rand.nextInt())`

Answer (score 8):

Consider a `byte`.  Its value ranges from -128 to 127.  Say your `byte` has a value of -100, then `Math.abs(-100)` will give you 100.  But what if the value of your byte is -128?  You cannot represent 128 as a `byte`, since the maximum value it can represent is 127.  So `Math.abs()` simply returns the *negative* parameter, unchanged.

The moral of the story is that it's possible for `Math.abs()` to return a negative value.

Comment: Correct, I think It depends on what the Math.abs() return, especially if the return value was  negative

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the plugin recognizes the specific case, `Math.abs(rand.nextInt())`.  So write something different.

The plug-in knows that that case doesn't always work:  It knows that rand.nextInt() can sometimes return Integer.MIN_VALUE, and it knows that Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE) can not be computed.  I would think about writing my own random number function that does not ever return Integer.MIN_VALUE.